# deleting intermediary folders

Tags: bash, file, robocopy, file-management

Maybe one of you guys has something like this at hand already? I tried to use robocopy on windows but to no avail. I also tried to write a bash script in linux with *find* etc... but gave up on that one also ^^ Google search brought no solution also unfortunately. I need this for my private photo library.

Solution could be linux or windows based, both are fine. Any ideas?

I would like to get rid of hundreds of 'intermediary folders'.

I define an 'intermediary folder' as a folder that contains nothing else than exactly one sub-folder. Example

```
folder 1
    file in folder 1
    folder 2            <-- 'intermediary folder: contains exactly one sub-folder, nothing else'
        folder 3
           file in folder 3
```

What I would like to end up with is:

```
 folder 1
      file in folder 1
      folder 3
           file in folder 3
```

I do not need the script to be recursive (removing several layers of intermediary folders at once), I'll just run it several times.

Even cooler would be if the script could rename folder 3 in the above example to 'folder 2 - folder 3', but I can live without this feature I guess.

I guess one of you linux experts has a one liner handy for that? ^^

Thank you very much!

Comment: Move `folder 3` to `folder 1` and remove empty `folder 2`?

Comment: @Cyrus thank you, but I need to do that on hundreds of folders, so I would need to write some kind of script. I edited the question to make that clearer. but good point, I can remove empty folders already with _robocopy rootfolder rootfolder /s /move_ so I just need to identify the folders to move and move them, and the removal of the empty folders can be done by robocopy then ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob
while IFS= read -rd '' dir; do
    f=("$dir"/*)
    if ((${#f[@]}==1)) && [[ -d $f ]]; then
        mv -t "${dir%/*}" "$f" || continue
        rm -r "$dir"
    fi  
done < <(find folder1 -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -print0)
```

**Explanation:**

- `shopt -s nullglob`: allows filename patterns which match no files to expand to a null string
- `find ... -depth`: makes `find` traverse the file system in a depth-first order
- `find ... -mindepth 1`: processes all directories except the starting-point
- `find ... -type d`: finds only directories
- `find ... -print0`: prints the directories separated by a null character `\0` (to correctly handle possible newlines in filenames)
- `while IFS= read ...`: loops over all the directories (the output of `find`)
- `f=("$dir"/*)`: creates an array with **all files** in the currently processed directory
- `((${#f[@]}==1)) && [[ -d $f ]]`: true if there is only one file and it is a directory

  - `mv -t "${dir%/*}" "$f"`: moves the only subdirectory one directory above
  - `mv ... || continue`: `mv` can fail if the subdirectory already exists in the directory above. `|| continue` ignores such subdirectory
  - `rm -r "$dir"`: removes the processed directory

---

**Test run:**

```
$ tree folder1
folder1
├── file1
├── folder2
│   └── folder3
│       └── file3
├── folder4
│   ├── file4a
│   ├── file4b
│   └── file4c
└── folder5
    └── folder6
        ├── file6
        └── folder7
            └── folder8
                └── folder9
                    ├── dir9
                    └── file9
$ ./script
$ tree folder1
folder1
├── file1
├── folder3
│   └── file3
├── folder4
│   ├── file4a
│   ├── file4b
│   └── file4c
└── folder6
    ├── file6
    └── folder9
        ├── dir9
        └── file9
```

Comment: considering the OP is quite unfamiliar with bash, I'd suggest adding comments and explanation. thanks

Comment: @baptistemm Waiting for OP to clarify this code works for him before writing an explanation in this case.

Comment: @PesaThe wow - thank you! I will give it a go tonight and let you know. googling the commands you used that i do not know yet might do the trick to get behind the magic ^^

Comment: @Peter I will gladly include an explanation.

Comment: @PesaThe wow this stackoverflow-thing - which is new to me - really gives me hope in us as the human race ^^ - but thanks, i am not completely unfamiliar with bash and am already looking forward to dissecting your script and trying to get behind it ^^

Comment: @Peter added explanation.

Comment: @PesaThe worked like a charm on both some test folders as well as real data. for the real folders i often get the problem that you describe _mv can fail if the subdirectory already exists in the directory above. || continue ignores such directory_ so thank you very much for adding that as well!